# Can not handle any event in a NSButton subclass

Tags: objective-c

I have my subclass of NSButton which is added as a subview to a NSView subclass:

```
[parentView addSubview:button];
```

All my click events are passed to the super view object.

I tried any example google found and yet I can not handle no event. I mean I tried these:

**In Button's init method:**

```
[self setTarget:self];

[self setAction:@selector(clicked)];
```

also

```
[self setTarget:self];

[self setAction:@selector(methodWithNSEventParam:)];
```

also have them commented.

Never got to "clicked".

**Overriding of the following methods (none of them ever called).**

> (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent
>
> (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent*)theEvent
>
> (BOOL) mouseDownCanMoveWindow
>
> (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
>
> (void) mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
>
> (NSView*) hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using Interface Builder.

Make sure you are setting the target, action, and event correctly. Here's an example for pageControl.

```
[pageControl addTarget:self
                action:@selector(pageTurning:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```